# Rails "acts-as-taggable-on": how to add tag *objects* to taggables, not by name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

In a data importer, I have code which is attempting to add a bunch of `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag` *objects* to a taggable's tag list:

```
    existing_item = FeedItem.where(url: item[:url]).first

    if existing_item.nil?
      new_item = FeedItem.new

      new_item.attributes = item.except(:id, :feeds)

      new_item.feeds = Feed.where(id: feeds_old_to_new(item_feeds, feeds))
      new_item.tag_list.add(
          ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.where(id: tags_old_to_new(item[:tags], tags)))

      new_item.save!
   else
      # ... merge imported record with existing item ...
   end
```

This doesn't work, because `tag_list.add` takes a list of tag *names*, not tag *objects*.  Is there any way to add tag *objects*?  I can't find anything in the acts-as-taggable-on documentation, and its code is much too magic for me to understand (for instance, [`Tag::concat`](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/tag_list.rb#L42) doesn't appear to mutate self!)

I could map the tags to their names, but then acts-as-taggable-on would run name canonicalization that is appropriate for user input but not for bulk data import, so I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 3):

The gem is really just adding this for you:

```
has_many :taggings
has_many :tags, through: :taggings
```

(It's a little more complicated to support multiple kinds of tags, but [the details](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/64ed839a8a6021c719fbff9c6bdf74a4fcd65f18/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable/core.rb) are pretty simple.)

So you can use those associations just like any other. In your case it'd be something like:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.where(id: tags_old_to_new(item[:tags], tags))).each do | t|
  new_item.tags << t
end
```

Comment: I have a distinct recollection of doing something that led me to believe that `FeedItem` objects do not _have_ a `tags` property. There are some weird things in [the definition of `FeedItem`](https://github.com/berkmancenter/tagteam/blob/master/app/models/feed_item.rb) - look specifically at what it's doing with `:tag_context_hierarchy`. Can you offer any additional advice on what might need to be changed in your answer to cope with that?

Comment: It has a simple [`acts_as_taggable` declaration](https://github.com/berkmancenter/tagteam/blob/master/app/models/feed_item.rb#L24). I don't see anything in `tag_context_hierarchy` to change that. You can see that [it even uses the `tags` association itself](https://github.com/berkmancenter/tagteam/blob/master/app/models/feed_item.rb#L185-L189).

Comment: Hmm, OK.  That's enough information that I can believe this _ought_ to work.  I timed the bounty badly; I won't be able to test this for another month or so.  I'm going to go ahead and give the bounty to you, but not accept the answer until I've actually tested it.

Comment: For the record, [this is the weird thing I was concerned about](https://github.com/berkmancenter/tagteam/blob/master/app/models/feed_item.rb#L59).

Comment: I don't think you need to be concerned about that. `acts_as_api` controls how instances are serialized to JSON when rendering an HTTP response, but it doesn't replace the `tags` method. (Right? I haven't used it, but I glanced at its docs.)

Comment: Your guess is probably better than mine - I don't even really speak Ruby. In retrospect, attempting to build on this particular Rails app may have been a mistake.